# CHECK: Prove that (gcd(a,b)=1 & $a*b=c^2$) $\rightarrow$ (($\exists$ u,v)($a=u^2$ & $b=v^2)$)

Tags: number-theory

Prove that (gcd(a,b)=1 & $a*b=c^2$) $\rightarrow$ (($\exists$ u,v)($a=u^2$ & $b=v^2)$)

If $a*b=c^2=c*c$ then a=c and b=c.

But $a \neq b$ because gcd(a,b)=1.

So for $a*b$ to be equal to a square then both a and b must each be squares.

Comment: No not quite: $ab=c^2$ does not imply $a=c$ and $b=c$ (take $a=4$ and $b=9$, $c=6$. Rather look at the prime factorization of $a$ and $b$! What can be said about the prime factors of $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [prime factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) let
$$a=\prod_{k=1}^n p_k^{\alpha_k}$$
and
$$b=\prod_{k=1}^m q_k^{\beta_k}$$
and since $a$ and $b$ are coprime then $p_i\ne q_j$ so since $ab$ is a square hence $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ are even and then $a$ and $b$ are also square.